# Ruby find by custom method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, methods, find

I am trying to figure out a way to search on an ActiveRecord model by its usual rails 3.0 syntax mixed in with custom methods.

For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def custom_method
   if [...]
     return true
   else 
     return false
   end     
 end
end
```

and I'd like to envoke this using ActiveRecord in such a way:

```
User.find(:all).where(custom_method is true)
```

Any ways to go about this? Apologies if the syntax isn't accurate for what I'm trying to convey.

EDIT: I'd like to clarify that `custom_method` used is fairly complex, so calling it instead of converting it to a sql syntax would be preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is typically implemented with a scope or with a class method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :active, -> { where(status: 'active') }

  def self.hidden
    where(status: 'hidden')
  end
end

# Both a scope and class method are then used the the same way
User.active # User.where(status: 'active')

User.where(foo: 'bar').active # User.where(foo: 'bar', status: 'active')
User.where(foo: 'bar').hidden # User.where(foo: 'bar', status: 'hidden')
```

If the `custom_method` is too complex or relies on properties not stored in the database, you may need to resort to filtering the items in memory.

```
User.where(foo: 'bar').to_a.select(&:custom_method)
```

Comment: see my only issue with this, is that it requires `status` to be in the User DB table? What if I merely want to query logic that isn't DB related?

Comment: added to the answer but you can just use in-memory filtering with `Array#select` or `Array#reject`

Comment: @nort thank you for your answer. is using `.select(&:custom_method)` performant?